# time complexity of sorting inside while loop

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to understand the time complexity of an algorithm with below pseudo code:

let nums has ArrayList of numbers

```
sort(nums)
while(nums.size() > 1) {
   // remove two elements
   nums.remove(0);
   nums.remove(0);

   nums.add(some_number);
   sort(nums);
}
```

`sort(nums)` is `(N)Log(N)`.
`nums.remove(0)` is `O(N)`
`nums.add()` is `O(1)`

Now what is the time complexity for this algorithm.

Comment: What do you think the time complexity is?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I was able to understand complexity per line, but not able to understand what it will be when I add a while loop

Comment: hint, how will the size of the list change, after an iteration in the `while` loop?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, list decreases by 1 element, so while loop runs `n` times. So I think the overall complexity is (N^2)Log (N) . Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final complexity is `O(n² log n)` since you do `n` times the operation `O(n log n)`.

Keep in mind that estimating complexity (`O(...)`) is not the same as establishing the total number of operations (usually the time function `T(...)` is given by total operations), they are two different concepts. A great introduction could be [Analysis of Algorithms](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Algorithmic%20Complexity/complexity.html)

Thus, the `O(...)` notation is a upper bound but `T(...)` is the real steps.

You can try to calculate exactly the `T` function, or you can go down the upper bound by improving `O`, but they will always be different functions, as `O` applies to the worst case of all possible entries.

In your code, we unknown `T` for the sort function, only their upper bound wich is `O(n log n)`, then:

```
T(n) ≤ O(n log n) + T(3) + O((n - 1) log (n - 1)) + T(3) + O((n - 2) log (n - 2) + ...
T(n) ≤ O(n log n) + n T(3) + n O(n log n)
                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

Here, we cannot define exactly the `T` for sorting operations on `n-1`, `n-2`, ... that is the reason for establishing as a higher level `O(n log n)` for all of them. Then:

```
T(n) ≤ O(n log n) + n T(3) + n O(n log n)
T(n) ≤ O(n log n) + O(n) + O(n² log n)
T(n) ≤ O(n² log n)
```

In the second expression, we have a **fixed number of upper bounds**, in which case the upper bound will be the highest of the upper bounds.

(remove, remove and add is `T(3)`, `goto` and comparisons are ignored)